# Using transactionsope in an action of a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting a "MSDTC on server 'ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS' is unavailable" error in the following code

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id;
   public string CustomerName;
   public string CustomerID;
}
```

The action from a controller which causes the error in question:

```
        public ActionResult CreateCustomerLogins()
        {
            List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>;
            customers = c.GetCustomerList(); // returns List<Customer>
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    foreach (Customer item in customers)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(item.CustomerName, item.CustomerID);
                    }
                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (TransactionAbortedException tae)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Error generating customer logins.");
            }


            return Json(new { });
        }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Express does not support MSDTC straight off the bat.

see if this helps:

http://alexduggleby.com/2008/08/24/msdtc-unavailable-for-sql-express-transactions-or-who-took-my-msdtc-settings-on-vista/

http://www.learningpenguin.net/myblog/2008/03/12/msdtc-on-server-sqlexpress-is-unavailable/

To fully enable MS DTC:

1.In Control Panel, open Administrative Tools, and then double-click Component Services.

2.In the left pane of Console Root, click Component Services, and then expand Computers.

3.Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.

4.On the MSDTC tab, click Security Configuration.

5.Under Security Settings, select all of the check boxes.

6.Verify that the DTC Logon Account name is set to NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Do you think that the way I used TransactionScope is valid? Would there be a rollback if the code inside it fails? :O

Comment: yes, the code is correct. if the transaction fails, you need to do a rollback, so dont call complete. so your code seems to be fine here. Take a look at this for more information and your reference.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete(v=vs.110).aspx